# Conditionally hide or show woocommerce product variation in fontend by custom field

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, conditional-content

I have added a custom field (checkbox) to product variations with the following code:

```
/**
* Create new fields for variations
*
*/
function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {

woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
array( 
    'id'            => '_wholesale_checkbox[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
    'label'         => 'Visa endast för företagskunder', 
    'description'   => '',
    'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_wholesale_checkbox', true ), 
    )
);

}
/**
 * Save new fields for variations
 *
*/
function save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {

// Checkbox
$checkbox = isset( $_POST['_wholesale_checkbox'][ $post_id ] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wholesale_checkbox', $checkbox );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
```

It adds the checkbox as desired as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

Now I want to conditionally hide or show the product variation in the frontend based on this field. The problem is I have some custom variation list in place (not my work) and I couldn't figure out how to get hold of the _wholesale_checkbox field to skip the variation (for which the checkbox is checked) in the loop that is outputting the list. See code for outputting the custom variation list below:

```
/**
 * Convert WooCommerce variation dropdown to radio buttons.
 *
 * @param string $html Original dropdown html.
 * @param array  $args Arguments.
 */
function ac_variation_radio_buttons( $html, $args ) {
$options   = $args['options'];
$product   = $args['product'];
$attribute = $args['attribute'];
$name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
$id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );

if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
}

// Output original dropdown element.
echo $html;

/* Create custom radio input list */
$html = '<section for="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="ac_variation_list_block">';

if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
    if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
        // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, [
            'fields' => 'all',
        ] );
        // var_dump($options);
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            /*
            if (**CUSTOM_FIELD is checked** )) {
                continue;
            }
            */
            if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                $html .= '<section class="ac_variation_option">';
                $html .= '<input id="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '_v" type="radio" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '_g" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '/>';
                $html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '_v"><span></span>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) ) . '</label>';
                $html .= '</section>';
            }
        }
    }
}

$html .= '</section>';

echo $html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'ac_variation_radio_buttons', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I ultimately solved this by manipulating the $options array. See full code below for conditionally hiding a product variation by a custom field, and display variations as radio buttons. Solution marked with comments

```
/**
* Convert WooCommerce variation dropdown to radio buttons.
*
* @param string $html Original dropdown html.
* @param array  $args Arguments.
*/
function ac_variation_radio_buttons( $html, $args ) {
$options   = $args['options'];
$product   = $args['product'];
$attribute = $args['attribute'];
$name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
$id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );

if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
}

// Output original dropdown element.
echo $html;

/**** ADDED CODE *****/
//Remove wholesale products for regular users
if($product->is_type( 'variable' )){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!in_array('fretagskund', $user->roles)){
        foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );

            if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                continue;
            }

            if(get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_wholesale_checkbox', true) === "yes" ){
                $attribute_name = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), 'attribute_pa_storlek', true);

                if ( in_array( $attribute_name, $options, true ) ) {
                    $options = array_diff($options, array($attribute_name));
                }

            }

        }
    }
}

/* Create custom radio input list */
$html = '<section for="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" class="ac_variation_list_block">';

if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
    if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
        // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, [
            'fields' => 'all',
        ] );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                $html .= '<section class="ac_variation_option">';
                $html .= '<input id="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '_v" type="radio" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '_g" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '/>';
                $html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '_v"><span></span>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) ) . '</label>';
                $html .= '</section>';
            }
        }
    }
}

$html .= '</section>';

echo $html;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'ac_variation_radio_buttons', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You should make a woocommerce plugin from this solution: "Show/Hide Product variation in the front end"

Answer (score 0):

Code to hide these variations from the standard WC dropdown:

Notes - 1. I'm using "b2bcustomer" role name, change as needed, 2. "gewicht" is my attribute slug, change as needed.

```
function hide_b2b_variations( $html, $args ) {
$options   = $args['options'];
$product   = $args['product'];
$attribute = $args['attribute'];
$name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
$id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );

if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
}

if($product->is_type( 'variable' )){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(in_array('b2bcustomer', $user->roles)){
        foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );

            if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                continue;
            }

            if(get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_wholesale_checkbox', true) === "yes" ){
                $attribute_name = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), 'attribute_pa_gewicht', true);
                if ( in_array( $attribute_name, $options, true ) ) {
                    $options = array_diff($options, array($attribute_name));
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
    

$html = '<select id="' . esc_attr( $id ) .'1'. '" class name="attribute_pa_gewicht" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_gewicht" data-show_option_none="yes"> ';

if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {
    if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {

        $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, [
            'fields' => 'all',
        ] );
    $html .='<option value>Choose an option</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                $html .= '<option value="' .esc_attr( $term->slug) .'" class="attached enabled">' .esc_attr( $term->name) .'</option>';

            }
        }
    }
}

$html .= '</select>';

echo $html;


}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'hide_b2b_variations', 10, 2 );
```

Also code for showing the new lowest price when hiding variations, or when showing all variations:
Note - I'm using "von" for the prefix, change it to "From" or something if needed

```
function variable_price_format( $price, $product ) {

$prefix = 'von ';

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(in_array('b2bcustomer', $user->roles)){
    $min_price_regular = 1000;
    $min_price_sale = 0;
        foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
            $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );

            if ( ! $variation || ! $variation->exists() ) {
                continue;
            }

            if(get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_wholesale_checkbox', true) === "no" ){
                $attribute_name = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), 'attribute_pa_gewicht', true);
                    $price_regular = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_regular_price', true);
                    $price_sale = get_post_meta($variation->get_id(), '_sale_price', true);

                if (($price_regular <= $min_price_regular)){
                    $min_price_regular = $price_regular;                
                }
                if (($price_sale > $min_price_sale)){
                 $min_price_sale = $price_sale;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($min_price_regular > $min_price_sale){
            return sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, wc_price($min_price_regular));
        }
        else return sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, wc_price($min_price_sale));
    }
    
    else 
    {
        $min_price_regular = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
        $min_price_sale = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
        $max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
        $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );


        $price = ( $min_price_sale == $min_price_regular ) ?
    
        wc_price( $min_price_regular ) :
        '' . wc_price( $min_price_regular ) . '' . '' . wc_price( $min_price_sale ) . '';
        return ( $min_price == $max_price ) ?
        $price :
        sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, $price);
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'variable_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variable_price_format', 10, 2 );
```